# Knockout for MVC. Child Dropdownlist doesn't load the model data at first time

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

**Model:**

```
public class StoreData
{
    public SelectList Regions { get; set; }
    public SelectList Groups { get; set; }
}
```

**Client:**

```
function CascadingDDLViewModel() {
    this.Groups = ko.observableArray([]);
}

var objVM = new CascadingDDLViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(objVM);
```

**HTML:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("gid", (SelectList)Model.Groups, new { id = "ddlGroup", data_bind = "options: Groups, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value'" })
```

**Jquery for Loading dropdown**

```
$("#ddlGroup").change(function () {
    var ddl = this;
    var id = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
    var url = $(ddl).attr("data-url");
    $.getJSON(url, { id: id }, function (data) { objVM.Stores(data); });
});
```

At first time after load data in the dependent dropdownList the data is absent. After choosing the item in parent list all is ok.

Problem comes after page is reload. How to bind data after page load?

Comment: have u used jquery...???

Comment: yes. For updating data:

Comment: $("#ddlGroup").change(function () {
        var ddl = this;
        var id = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
        var url = $(ddl).attr("data-url");
        $.getJSON(url, { id: id }, function (data) {
            objVM.Stores(data);
        });
    });

Comment: I don't think you're grasping the concept of MVVM very well. You're not supposed to bind event handlers to the DOM. It doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Blackraven I do suggest you go through the tutorials at http://learn.knockoutjs.com/. You'll probably get a better grasp of the MVVM concepts there, and also you'll see a few samples on how to work with drop down lists using knockout.

Comment: Before using I read tutorial on learn.knockoutjs.com site. All the same thank for a link.
May be I not full understand MVVM pattern but In my example don't need it.
All I try to change it big code on more smaller by using binding.

Comment: I have only one question.Why the dependent list overwrites the data transmitted in the model

Answer (score 0):

I decided my problem using only the one line

```
$('#ddlRegion').trigger('change');
```

All working correctly now. But I have one problem. Now I am not full understand it moment. How can I use MVC Model for set defaul data after loading. It data have been formed using depending.

```
StoreData store = new StoreData();

            store.Regions = _dataManager.Monitorings.GetRegionsSelectList(Region_id, true);
            store.Region_id =  (Region_id == -1 ? (int)store.Regions.SelectedValue : Region_id);

            store.Groups = _dataManager.Monitorings.GetStoreGroupsSelectList(store.Region_id, Group_id);
            store.Group_id = Group_id;
```

Earlier I used it method:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("sid", (SelectList)Model.Stores, new { id = "ddlStore" })
```

Now:

```
    @Html.DropDownList("sid", (SelectList)Model.Stores, new { id = "ddlStore", data_bind = "options: Stores, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value'" })
```

I understand that must set Client Model data. But don't understand how do it?
Now array is empty:

```
this.Groups = ko.observableArray([]);
```